# What does "two-way justice" mean?

Tags: phrase-usage, meaning

What does "two-way justice" mean? Can I use it to describe a relationship between two people (without considering the role of gender) in which there is a complete equality in behaviors and reactions?

Comment: I think this question with its current title is Not Constructive, since [two-way justice](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E2%80%9Ctwo-way+justice%E2%80%9D&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) isn't an established term with a defined meaning. That link finds only 10 written instances in Google Books, within which it's clearly used with several different senses - a judicial system treating different social groups differently, or any arrangement whereby two parties mutually deliver "justice" to the other, for example.

Comment: Thanks for expressing your idea however I disagree with you. I will make a topic in meta to find what constructive question mean to help you make clear some ambiguous terms like this which you use here a lot and it may confuse many non English speakers.

Comment: If your question was titled something like *Is there a common term for "complete equality in the quality of behaviors and reactions"*, I wouldn't have a problem. But as it stands, you appear to be asking for the "meaning" of a term which is effectively non-existent, and therefore doesn't *have* an established meaning.

Comment: when you can find it in the internet so this term exists ,although for wider usages or different usages not personal relationships.

Comment: If you'd linked to a specific instance of someone using the term "two-way justice", and asked what it meant, I'd have probably said it was Too Localised, on the grounds that it's only used 10 times (with conflicting senses) in Google Books. But as I said, if you'd asked for a term to describe what you apparently have in mind, I'd have upvoted StoneyB's [mutual respect](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mutual+respect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as the obvious choice, given that there are over 1,000,000 written instances of that in my link.

Comment: Don't try to read too much into the meaning of "too localized" or "not constructive". Those are simply [multiple choice options](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/valid-question-closed-as-too-localised-requesting-reasons-for-being-out-of-sc/3095#3095). When someone tells you your question seems too localized, or general reference, instead of arguing with them, invest that energy into improving your question. And don't be insulted – even highly ranked users get questions closed from time to time. No one is lambasting _you_, they are simply addressing this particular question.

Comment: There is a history behind it which has been deleted before. Thanks for your advices but before I argued to know the reason which at first time no body tried to answer me and instead I faced to being frozen,suspended and insulted! Surely everything is not available but in this time people tried to be more tolerate,calm and reasonable in answering so I tried to invest my energy to improve my questions not arguing with them because they corrected their wrong behaviors so now I have corrected myself too!.. A real two-way fairness! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Just* and *justice*, at least in US use, tend to be restricted to talk about law, or systems like the legal system. They are not ordinarily be used with respect to personal relationships; there, *fair* and *fairness* are more likely.

Better terms for what you are trying to express might be *mutual fairness* or *mutual respect*.

Comment: Look at this for example: http://knowledge.sagepub.com/view/criminal-and-social-justice/n2.xml. Justice as a two-way street.

Comment: @user37324 Note that the book is referring to *criminal* and *social* justice. Criminal justice is, as StoneyB suggested, a legal matter. Social justice is also related to legal issues, though in a somewhat different way; where criminal justice refers to a broken law, social justice generally refers to a broken social system that is harming many people. In both cases, the word "justice" is used to refer to larger issues, either dealing with the law or dealing with widespread problems affecting many people. Justice is rarely used to discuss personal relationships.

Comment: Can I use of it as a kind of friendly sarcasm to show the importance of the quality of my relationship with another one?

Comment: @user37324  You *can* use it any way you want. Your hearer(s) or reader(s) will understand you to be making an analogy to law and social institutions; if that's what you want, you're fine. But it's your hearers who decide what you mean, not you.

Comment: You got it! It can be a problem. I used to indirect and poetic/ironic usage of words,idioms and phrases in my own motherhood tongue which sounds very nice and interesting for most of people from different social levels and I have to fix it or change this habit when I try to speak or write in English to not make confusion,offense or ambiguity.

Comment: I confess it was my main goal to join this site! :)

Comment: @user37324  Any time you employ indirection or irony you are inviting misunderstanding--literally inviting it for rhetorical effect. Questions on this site should be directed toward literal meanings, or unambiguous ironies; questions about utterances of the sort you describe are inherently Not Constructive.

Comment: Surely I do not mean about my questions but about phrases and terms which I use of them in my own motherhood language and cannot find the equivalent in English to convey my reason and at the same moment enjoy of playing with words and phrases.

Comment: @user37324 Language is a dangerous toy to play with.

Comment: Yes! Surely! A two-edged sword for all users! Thanks! :))